# EMR & Spark adding dependencies after cluster creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, elastic-map-reduce

Is it possible to install additional libs/dependencies after the cluster is already up and running?

Things I've done that are related to this:

- I've already done the pre-creation bootstrapping process (this is a different solution altogether)
- alternatively, SSH'd into each node and installed dependencies after the cluster comes up

I think the post-startup installation solution would involve being able to fire off a command to all the executors from the driver. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want additional dependencies to your steps, you can add them in the command of the step ( i.e. for Spark use the --jars option )